# Check if two consecutive values in a dataframe column are bigger than 0

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to check if two consecutive values in a column are bigger than 0. If yes, then `data['Exit'] = 1, else 0`

My code:

```
data['Exit'] = 0

for row in range(len(data)):
    if (data['Mkt_Return'].iloc[row] > 0) and (data['Mkt_Return'].iloc[row-1] > 0):
        data['Exit'] = 1
```

Right now all my values are equal to 1, but I know some values are smaller than 0 and therefore shouldn't be equal to 1.

Is  `.iloc[row-1]` wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input data, i.e., values in the `Mkt_Return` column, and show the desired output, i.e., values in the `Exit` column? What do you want the first `Exit` value to be (that is, the value of the first row)?

Comment: Mkt_return are daily returns of the S&P500. I want to implement a take profit after two consecutive up days. So e.g., the S&P500 rises on Monday and Tuesday, i would like to close my position on wednesday. Therefore i'd like to see when the S&P did rise two days in a row

Answer (score 1):

Your condition logic is a bit faulty, for instance, it compares the first row data with the last row data. You might need to correct to maybe this form

```
for row in range(1,len(data)):
  if ((data['Mkt_Return'].iloc[row-1] > 0) and (data['Mkt_Return'].iloc[row] > 0)):
    data['Exit'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still only receive 1's

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
data["Mkt_Return_2"] = data["Mkt_Return"].shift(-1)
import numpy as np
data["foo"] = np.where(((data["Mkt_Return_2"] > 0) & (data["Mkt_Return"] > 0)), 1, 0)
```

Comment: An added suggestion is try to solve dataframe problems without looping. You will miss out on a huge performance advantage if you loop.